# How to highlight particular line inside <pre> and iterate based on particular word?

Tags: javascript, html, css, regex

I have a text data which are set of code lines inside pre tag and that code lines have some failure lines which is indicated by FAIL. I have one button named 'Next Fail' and on clicking over it I want to highlight the line inside pre tag which has the word 'FAIL' and iterate over it to highlight the next line which has 'FAIL' keyword in it.

Sample data inside pre tag

```
00:00:00 INFO SERVER-SYSTEM - Cmd Line Arg: sysName = SERVER
00:00:01 INFO SERVER-SYSTEM - Cmd Line Arg: resultsDirName = github
00:00:02 INFO SERVER-SYSTEM - Cmd Line Arg: Device4Branch = //github/server_manager01/test1
00:00:02 FAIL SERVER-SYSTEM - Cmd Line Arg: testCase = server_manager01
00:00:03 INFO SERVER-SYSTEM - Cmd Line Arg: timestamp_style = RELATIVE
00:00:04 INFO SERVER-SYSTEM - Cmd Line Arg: token = 36
00:00:04 FAIL SERVER-SYSTEM - Cmd Line Arg: Campaign = True
```

So when I click on 'Next Fail' button, the line which has 'FAIL' word should be highlighted with red border and on clicking further it should highlight the next line which has the word.

I have coded to print the line which has word 'FAIL' but unable to highlight it and iter over. Following is what I have coded.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var count = 0;
        $("#next_fail").click(function(){
          var x = document.getElementById("code").textContent;
          var lines = x.split('\n');

          li = 0;
          for(i=0;i<lines.length;i++){
            x = lines[i];
            var n = x.search("FAIL");
            if (n>0)
              li = i;
          }
          alert(li);
        });


    });
</script>
```

Do let me know what are changes to be done in order to iter over 'FAIL' keyword by highlighting with red border.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could map the lines and add for example a div and keep track which id's have the word FAIL using [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) and add those to an array.

```
if (lines[i].includes("FAIL")) indicesWithFail.push(i);
```

If you want a more precise match, you could use this line instead with a time like pattern followed by FAIL.

```
if (/\d+:\d+:\d+ FAIL /.test(lines[i])) indicesWithFail.push(i);
```

Highlight the current div by for example setting a border color and remove the border for the previous one.

For example with some inline comments:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let indicesWithFail = [];
  let currentIndex = null;
  let lines = document.getElementById("code").innerHTML.split('\n');
  let idPrefix = "line_";
  let redBorder = "1px solid red";

  // map the entries to a div to enable styling and track the index if the line contains FAIL
  lines = lines.map((value, index) => {
    if (lines[index].includes("FAIL")) indicesWithFail.push(index);
    return `<div id='${idPrefix}${index}'>${value}</div>`;
  });

  // put the mapped content back as innerHTML of the PRE element
  document.getElementById("code").innerHTML = lines.join("\n");

  $("#next_fail").click(function() {
    if (indicesWithFail.length > 0) {
      // remove the border of the previous element
      document.getElementById(`${idPrefix}${indicesWithFail[currentIndex]}`).style.border = "";
      currentIndex++;

      // reset to loop from the start
      if (currentIndex >= indicesWithFail.length) currentIndex = 0;
      // set the border for the current element
      document.getElementById(`${idPrefix}${indicesWithFail[currentIndex]}`).style.border = redBorder;
    }
  });

  // initialize
  if (indicesWithFail.length > 0) {
    // set the start index if we have FAIL entries
    currentIndex = 0;
    // set a red border for the first entry
    document.getElementById(`${idPrefix}${indicesWithFail[currentIndex]}`).style.border = redBorder;
  }
});
```

```css
pre div {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre id="code">
00:00:00 INFO SERVER-SYSTEM - Cmd Line Arg: sysName = SERVER
00:00:01 INFO SERVER-SYSTEM - Cmd Line Arg: resultsDirName = github
00:00:02 INFO SERVER-SYSTEM - Cmd Line Arg: Device4Branch = //github/server_manager01/test1
00:00:02 FAIL SERVER-SYSTEM - Cmd Line Arg: testCase = server_manager01
00:00:03 INFO SERVER-SYSTEM - Cmd Line Arg: timestamp_style = RELATIVE
00:00:04 INFO SERVER-SYSTEM - Cmd Line Arg: token = 36
00:00:04 FAIL SERVER-SYSTEM - Cmd Line Arg: Campaign = True
</pre>

<form>
  <input id="next_fail" type="button" value="Next">
</form>
```

For longer pages, with Jquery animate:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let indicesWithFail = [];
  let currentIndex = null;
  let lines = document.getElementById("code").innerHTML.split('\n');
  let idPrefix = "line_";
  let redBorder = "1px solid red";

  // map the entries to a div to enable styling and track the index if the line contains FAIL
  lines = lines.map((value, index) => {
    if (lines[index].includes("FAIL")) indicesWithFail.push(index);
    return `<div id='${idPrefix}${index}'>${value}</div>`;
  });

  // put the mapped content back as innerHTML of the PRE element
  document.getElementById("code").innerHTML = lines.join("\n");

  $("#next_fail").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (indicesWithFail.length > 0) {
      // remove the border of the previous element
      document.getElementById(`${idPrefix}${indicesWithFail[currentIndex]}`).style.border = "";
      currentIndex++;

      // reset to loop from the start
      if (currentIndex >= indicesWithFail.length) currentIndex = 0;
      // set the border for the current element
      let elm = document.getElementById(`${idPrefix}${indicesWithFail[currentIndex]}`);
      elm.style.border = redBorder;
      $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(elm).offset().top - 40
      }, 'fast');
    }
  });

  // initialize
  if (indicesWithFail.length > 0) {
    // set the start index if we have FAIL entries
    currentIndex = 0;
    // set a red border for the first entry
    let elm = document.getElementById(`${idPrefix}${indicesWithFail[currentIndex]}`);
    elm.style.border = redBorder;
    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(elm).offset().top - 40
    }, 'fast');
  }
});
```

```css
#next_fail {
  position: fixed;
  height: 30px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre id="code">
00:00:00 INFO SERVER-SYSTEM - Cmd Line Arg: sysName = SERVER
00:00:01 INFO SERVER-SYSTEM - Cmd Line Arg: resultsDirName = github
00:00:02 INFO SERVER-SYSTEM - Cmd Line Arg: Device4Branch = //github/server_manager01/test1
00:00:02 FAIL SERVER-SYSTEM - Cmd Line Arg: testCase = server_manager01
00:00:03 INFO SERVER-SYSTEM - Cmd Line Arg: timestamp_style = RELATIVE
00:00:04 INFO SERVER-SYSTEM - Cmd Line Arg: token = 36
00:00:04 FAIL SERVER-SYSTEM - Cmd Line Arg: Campaign = True
00:00:00 INFO SERVER-SYSTEM - Cmd Line Arg: sysName = SERVER
00:00:01 INFO SERVER-SYSTEM - Cmd Line Arg: resultsDirName = github
00:00:02 INFO SERVER-SYSTEM - Cmd Line Arg: Device4Branch = //github/server_manager01/test1
00:00:02 FAIL SERVER-SYSTEM - Cmd Line Arg: testCase = server_manager01
00:00:03 INFO SERVER-SYSTEM - Cmd Line Arg: timestamp_style = RELATIVE
00:00:04 INFO SERVER-SYSTEM - Cmd Line Arg: token = 36
00:00:04 FAIL SERVER-SYSTEM - Cmd Line Arg: Campaign = True
00:00:00 INFO SERVER-SYSTEM - Cmd Line Arg: sysName = SERVER
00:00:01 INFO SERVER-SYSTEM - Cmd Line Arg: resultsDirName = github
00:00:02 INFO SERVER-SYSTEM - Cmd Line Arg: Device4Branch = //github/server_manager01/test1
00:00:02 FAIL SERVER-SYSTEM - Cmd Line Arg: testCase = server_manager01
00:00:03 INFO SERVER-SYSTEM - Cmd Line Arg: timestamp_style = RELATIVE
00:00:04 INFO SERVER-SYSTEM - Cmd Line Arg: token = 36
00:00:04 FAIL SERVER-SYSTEM - Cmd Line Arg: Campaign = True
00:00:00 INFO SERVER-SYSTEM - Cmd Line Arg: sysName = SERVER
00:00:01 INFO SERVER-SYSTEM - Cmd Line Arg: resultsDirName = github
00:00:02 INFO SERVER-SYSTEM - Cmd Line Arg: Device4Branch = //github/server_manager01/test1
00:00:02 FAIL SERVER-SYSTEM - Cmd Line Arg: testCase = server_manager01
00:00:03 INFO SERVER-SYSTEM - Cmd Line Arg: timestamp_style = RELATIVE
00:00:04 INFO SERVER-SYSTEM - Cmd Line Arg: token = 36
00:00:04 FAIL SERVER-SYSTEM - Cmd Line Arg: Campaign = True
00:00:00 INFO SERVER-SYSTEM - Cmd Line Arg: sysName = SERVER
00:00:01 INFO SERVER-SYSTEM - Cmd Line Arg: resultsDirName = github
00:00:02 INFO SERVER-SYSTEM - Cmd Line Arg: Device4Branch = //github/server_manager01/test1
00:00:02 FAIL SERVER-SYSTEM - Cmd Line Arg: testCase = server_manager01
00:00:03 INFO SERVER-SYSTEM - Cmd Line Arg: timestamp_style = RELATIVE
00:00:04 INFO SERVER-SYSTEM - Cmd Line Arg: token = 36
00:00:04 FAIL SERVER-SYSTEM - Cmd Line Arg: Campaign = True
00:00:00 INFO SERVER-SYSTEM - Cmd Line Arg: sysName = SERVER
00:00:01 INFO SERVER-SYSTEM - Cmd Line Arg: resultsDirName = github
00:00:02 INFO SERVER-SYSTEM - Cmd Line Arg: Device4Branch = //github/server_manager01/test1
00:00:02 FAIL SERVER-SYSTEM - Cmd Line Arg: testCase = server_manager01
00:00:03 INFO SERVER-SYSTEM - Cmd Line Arg: timestamp_style = RELATIVE

</pre>

<form>
  <input id="next_fail" type="button" value="Next Fail">
</form>
```

Comment: The content inside pre could be of multiple lines so in order to scroll down automatically to the highlighted line, what edits need to be done?

Comment: What do you mean by multiple lines? The lines are single lines that contain FAIL right?

Comment: If there 100+ lines of content inside pre tag then there will be scroll bar so if FAIL keyword is at the end and when clicked on Next button it should automatically scroll down to the highlighted line. So how can that be achieved?

Comment: @AbhishekBhandari You could play around with for example Jquery scrollTop. I have added another code example.